Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.config/svgrrc' when launching a fresh npm project
Received a error message:
Failed to compile.                                 

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.config/svgrrc'  

when launching a fresh npm project using npm start
The project is created via npx create-react-app test
One of solution is chmod directory permission.
However, my question is how to change the config directory, e.g., replacing the directory /.config by another directory /home/....  As the /.config  does not make sense for me.

npm --version
10.8.2
nvm --version
0.40.0
